# Meteor : Iterate through array of Objects inside an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, collections

I'm currently trying to iterate through an array of Objects inside an Object.
I have my Collection "Proposals", and this is the corresponding Schema :

```
Schemas.ProposalsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  'content': {
    type: String,
    max: 140
  },
  'parties': {
    type: [Object],
    autoform : {
      type: "select-multiple"
    }
  },
  'parties.$._id': {
    type: Object,
    optional: true
  },
  'parties.$._id._str': {
    type: String
  },
  'parties.$.name': {
    type: String
  }
});
```

I would like to iterate through the array of parties inside one of my template. I tried this :

```
{{#each proposals}}
    <p>{{content}}</p>
    <p>{{#each parties}} {{this.name}} {{/each}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

The content is displayed, but not the name of the different parties. Here's my template helper :

```
Template.proposalsIndex.helpers({
  proposals: () => Proposals.find().fetch()
});
```

Do you know what do i do wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does not work either

Comment: look in the client console if your data is getting passed from server or not.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks ok.

Things you need to check are:

1. Is the "parties" field populated in a database? (you can run `Proposals.find().fetch()` in a `meteor shell` to check it).

   If not, find out why it is not populated.
2. Is the "parties" field published to client? (you can run `Proposals.find().fetch()` in a browser console and see the results).

   If not, check your publication.